# computer vision to separate characters from image

Tags: ocr, vision

[image: image 1]

I'm trying to separate text from a background that has very similar background.
any idea on how to extract HDP 250?

Comment: I tried Canny edge and Sobel Derivatives

Comment: I mean StackOverflow is not a free code service, someone may help you fixing a problem with your actual code, but show your attemp and where you're stuck. (I've no competence on this, I just try to help you improve your question so competent people could better help you)

Answer (score 0):

The simple way would be to create a database of how each letter should look like. Then use template matching to find most probable letter. You will have to make some restrictions regarding image orientation, scale and illumination, they cannot vary too much. Also learn how empty space should look like and only consider a letter when its probably of presence is higher than an empty space one.